# A proper way to check if email exists sequelize (node js)?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, authentication, sequelize.js

I'm starting with sequelize and to test it, i'm building a user registration system.
I have a UNIQUE constraint on the email FIELD, because i don't want multiple users to have the same email.
To check if a email it's already registered i'm using this if statement:

```
           const emailExists = (await User.findOne()).where('email', email);
           if (emailExists) return res.json("Email already registered")
```

But i kinda feel that this isn't the correct approach to do it.
Can anyone tell me if that's a better (what i think so) to check if the email is already registered?

I also have this index: `"users_unique_lower_email_idx" UNIQUE, btree (lower(email::text))` on my table that doesn't seems to work when performing the check, if anyone know way and can anwer me i'd be glad.

Comment: "Better approach" is a matter of opinion. In your case, you could do a `User.count` and set LIMIT to 1, then if its `1` it exists `0` if not. Then its more of a `boolean` so to say instead of `null` or `undefined` . Then there are other validations you can use sequelizeto apply as well on each model.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```js
  const emailExists = await User.findOne({ where: { email: 'email' } });
if (emailExists ) {
  res.json("Email already registered")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let email = req.params.email
const emailExists = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } });
if (emailExists ) {
    res.json("Email already registered")
}
```

I think this would be a better way so you can dynamically check any email